# Randomly sampling an item always returns the same value

Tags: random, scheme, random-seed, gauche

I am attempting to write a script that samples one of my colleagues' names randomly:

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/env gosh -b

(define-module utils
  (use data.random :only (samples$ integers-between$))
  (use gauche.generator :only (generator->list))
  (export generator->first
          sample1)

  (define (generator->first gen)
    (car (generator->list gen 1)))

  (define (sample1 items)
    (generator->first (samples$ items))))


(import (utils :only (sample1)))

(define team-members
  (list "billy"
        "nilly"
        "silly"
        "willy"))

(define (main args)
  (print (sample1 team-members))
  0)
```

However it always emits the same value:

```bash
for i in {1..25}; do
  gosh ./random-team-member
done
```

Why is this happening?

Do I need to somehow initialize the random number generator? Am I misusing `generator->list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe [the documentation for `data.random`](https://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/gauche-refe/Random-data-generators.html).

> The random seed is initialized by a fixed value when the module is loaded. You can get and set the random seed [with *`random-data-seed`*].

I don't see any obvious way to initialize the random seed from some other source of randomness, such as the system clock. So if you want unpredictable randomness, you'll need to find entropy yourself - perhaps read from /dev/urandom?

Comment: I was able to get a random seed from `/dev/urandom` with: `(use binary.io) (use data.random) (set! (random-data-seed) (call-with-input-file "/dev/urandom" read-u32))`.